# Printing Vector Members. error

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

I need to sort then print the result increasing and decreasing. I have some problems with my printing.

Code:

```
 void srtAsc(Array M){
    vector <int> days[31];

for(int i=0; i<31; i++){
    int s=0;
    for(int j = 0; j<6; j++){
        s += M.M[i][j];
        days[i] = s; //// HERE

    }
 sort(days[0],days[31]);
 }
 for(int i=0; i<31;i++){
    cout<<i<<". "<<days[i]; ///// HERE 
    cout<<endl;
 }
  }
```

ERROR:
///// HERE spots I get also an error, maybe they are related. " No match oeprators '='

```
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2072:4: error: no   match for 'operator--' in '--__next'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2074:7: error: no match for 'operator*' in '*__last'
```

Comment: Do you realize you created an array of 31 vectors and not a vector with a capacity of 31?

Comment: What is an `Array`?  Please post a [**minimal** test-case](http://sscce.org), and the **complete** error message.

Comment: WooaaA? :)) seriosly?  it is not  vector <type> name <size> the patern?

Comment: Array is a 2D matrix which i use as argument since i need the data from there.

Comment: could we have a piece of code we can inspect better compiling? (if you do not want to put your whole code - I hope so - try to extract the minimal compilable "unit" you can, test it to be sure that it shows the problem, and then put it here)

Comment: To set the size in the constructor see here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/ . The syntax is `()` not `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STL algorithms, like `sort`, operate on *iterators*, so you will need to call `sort` like this:

```
sort(days.begin(), days.end());
```

But first, fix your code: you have created 31 vectors - not a vector with 31 elements. Use

```
vector<int> days(31);
```

Comment: it works for me no  error/bugg around there.. there isa problem when i try to assign to the values from my Array M to the vector.
   s += M.M[i][j];
   days[i] = s;
and when i try to rpint the vector  out it has something with the = operator.

Comment: days[i] = s fails because days[i] is of type vector<int> and not int. That's the point of the bug I am talking about.

Comment: fixed... could you give em a hint how to fix the difference between int adn vec<int>?so i can move them from M to days?